# ImageChooserPanel wrongfully showing as Select widget

Tags: wagtail

I find stack overflow very difficult to use and I am probably going to be slammed for trying but here goes.

I am trying to get an image field to bring up the standard wagtail image chooser dialog but it's displaying in wagtail admin as a Select widget with no option to upload new image.

```
from django.db import models

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.core.models import Page, Orderable
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel

from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (
    FieldPanel,
    MultiFieldPanel,
    InlinePanel,
    PageChooserPanel,
)
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel

class HomePage(Page):
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)

        # Add extra variables and return the updated context
        context['sections'] = Sections.objects.all()
        return context


class Sections(ClusterableModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = False, null= True)
    section_image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    panels = [
        FieldPanel("title"),
        ImageChooserPanel("section_image"),
        InlinePanel("albums"),
    ]

class Albums(ClusterableModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = False, null= True)
    section = ParentalKey("Sections", related_name="albums")

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("title"),
        InlinePanel("images"),
    ]
class GalleryImage(Orderable):
    album = ParentalKey("Albums", related_name="images")
    galleryimage = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel("galleryimage"),
    ]
```

This is probably a rookie mistake and would appreciate if someone can show me why gallery image is not rendering correctly.

Comment: Good question, and no slamming for trying mate – keep asking :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is an open bug in Wagtail: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/5126

Historically, nesting `InlinePanel`s has not been well-supported in Wagtail - there are some [improvements in progress](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/5566) which will hopefully make it into the forthcoming 2.7 release, but this particular issue is still outstanding.